# Javascript updating values of objects inside list

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects

```
var list = [
{"index" : "1", "name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "2","name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "3","name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "4","name": "abc", "value":123}
];
```

The user will be able to edit the value property. 
**Note this is displayed in an app** 
[image: SCREENSHOT OF THE SCREEN OF THE APP]

My Question is how to make changes in the array when they edit the values. Any ideas on how it can be done?

**The input user gives will be numbers or float**

Comment: I can't give a complete answer because you don't state what kind of input you want from your client. Is it supposed to be increase/decrease? Or only numbers? Or free text?

Comment: I created the whole app in my answer. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
Array.prototype.setName = function(index, value) {
    this.filter(function(v) {
        return v.index == index ? v.name = value : v;
    })
}

Array.prototype.setValue = function(index, value) {
    this.filter(function(v) {
        return v.index == index ? v.value = value : v;
    })
}

var list = [
{"index" : "1", "name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "2","name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "3","name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "4","name": "abc", "value":123}
];

list.setName(2,"qwe");
list.setValue(2,456);


list.setValue(3,789);

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Adding methods or properties on the prototype of built-in Objects like `Array` is widely considered harmful and really bad practice.

Comment: As a reference https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

Comment: @connexo Just like McDonald's makes people fat, but it is delicious. 
The most important thing about programming is to solve problems, not to deliberately follow the rules. 
By the way, don't use getElementById instead, use querySelector instead.

Comment: Why would I?  `document.getElementById(id)` should be faster by orders of magnitude compared to `document.querySelector(\`#${id}\`)`.

Answer (score 0):

You would reference them as list[i].property e.g

```
list[1].name = "dave";
```

Comment: But i would have to run a for loop every time a user updates a value

Comment: @SanjeevMUFC no you dont you only need to take the array index on the saved value

Comment: Thanks @AmitWagner

Answer (score 0):

using ES6 destructuring update by index property
(u should consider using number on "index" property and somehow to match it with array index is going to be confusing)

```js
let list = [
{"index" : "1", "name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "2","name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "3","name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "4","name": "abc", "value":123}
];


const updateValueByIndex = (list, index, newValue)=>{
    list[index-1]={
      ...list[index-1],
      value:newValue
    }
    //or just list[index-1].value=newValue;
};

updateValueByIndex(list, "1", 33)
console.log(list)
```

Comment: *ES6 destruction*  should probably be **ES6 destructuring**.

Answer (score -1):

Here's you whole app in vanilla Javascript:

```js
const list = [
{"index" : "1", "name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "2","name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "3","name": "abc", "value":123},
{"index" : "4","name": "abc", "value":123}
];

const app = document.getElementById('app');
const code = document.getElementById('code');

for (const item of list) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  let label = document.createElement('label');
  
  input.type = "number";
  input.id = `input-${item.index}`;
  input.value = item.value;
  input.dataset.index = item.index;
  
  label.setAttribute('for', input.id);
  label.textContent = item.name;
  
  input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    list[e.target.dataset.index-1].value = e.target.value;
    code.textContent = JSON.stringify(list);
  })
  
  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(label);
  console.log(div.outerHTML);
  app.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<hr />
<code id="code"></code>
```

If all you need is a function that updates a given property with a given value under a given index in any array containing objects, here you go (without modifying objects you don't own, like `Array.prototype`):

```js
const list = [
  {"index" : "1", "name": "abc", "value":123},
  {"index" : "2","name": "abc", "value":123},
  {"index" : "3","name": "abc", "value":123},
  {"index" : "4","name": "abc", "value":123}
];

function updateArrayItem(index, prop, value) {
   this.filter(function(i, idx) { return index == i.index ? i[prop] = value : i})
   return this;
}

updateArrayItem.call(list, 1, 'name', 'cba')
updateArrayItem.call(list, 2, 'value', 321)

console.log(list);
```